# How to check whether "File open..." window is open with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an keyup handler. I want something to happen every time I press ESC *except* when I'm inside a "Choose File..." window.

Here is a jQuery sample code of what I need:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        if (!IsChooseFileDialogBoxOpen())
            doSomething();
    }
});
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The "choose file" window is outside your jurisdiction. There's no way to do this (and the event won't fire anyway).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's impossible.

Comment: Isn't the Open file dialog going to ignore your `keyup` event anyway?  You don't need to handle that case.

Comment: @Pekka No, the event does fire. The `keyup` event will be caught by JS, even though `keydown` is caught by the dialog (at least in FF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, per-say. But what might be able to do is switch to use the `keydown` or `keypress` events instead of `keyup`. Then when the user presses ESC with the file dialog open, the `keydown` event is caught by the dialog and not sent to your JS, so the callback never fires.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/sHKjb/
I tested this in FF, did not do any further testing for Chrome, IE, etc.